# How to set container specific options in Aurelia-Dragula?

Tags: aurelia, dragula

I'm using Aurelia-Dragula (https://github.com/michaelmalonenz/aurelia-dragula) in my application and I want to set my options per container like in non-Aurelia Dragula.

In my case I want to have ContainerA where I want option.copy = true and ContainerB where I want option.removeOnSpill = true. so I tried both:

```
.plugin('aurelia-dragula', (options) => {
            options.removeOnSpill = true;
            options.copy = true;
        })
```

But the result is that copy reigns and removeOnSpill doesn't work.

How options variable looks in aurelia-dragula when logged to the console:
`{"containers":[],"copy":true,"copySortSource":false,"revertOnSpill":true,"removeOnSpill":true,"direction":"vertical","ignoreInputTextSelection":true,"mirrorContainer":{}}`

Example of how it's done in non-Aurelia Dragula (source: https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/):

```
dragula([document.getElementById(left), document.getElementById(right)], {
  copy: function (el, source) {
    return source === document.getElementById(left)
  },
  accepts: function (el, target) {
    return target !== document.getElementById(left)
  }
});
```

Due to how different the options is set and I can't find documentation for this in aurelia-dragula I'm not able to translate it.

Comment: It seems the author recently just introduced some changes to the lib, maybe you should ask in the repo? I know it's against the spirit of bug filing, but it's still light traffic there so I guess he wouldn't mind answering you there. If you could get an answer, would be awesome if you could post a link back here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I didn't want to ask in the repo for the same reasons you describe, but I may do so tomorrow if there's no more responses here.

Comment: Created issue in the repo: https://github.com/michaelmalonenz/aurelia-dragula/issues/52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Righto - so yes, it's absolutely possible.

I haven't tested this, but I believe this will work:

view.html

```
<template>
  <aurelia-dragula containers.one-way="containers" copy.call="shouldCopy(item, container)" accepts.call="shouldAccept(item, target, source, reference)"></aurelia-dragula>
</template>
```

viewmodel.js

```
export class ViewModel {

  get containers () {
    return [document.getElementById(left), document.getElementById(right)]
  }

  shouldCopy (item, container) {
    return container === document.getElementById(left)
  }

  shouldAccept(item, target, source, reference) {
    return target !== document.getElementById(left)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for partially solving the issue.
What remains is that shouldCopys parameters are undefined, while shouldAccept works fine. 

Looked in the aurelia-binding.js and when it runs evalList on the parameters for shouldAccept they are populated, while shouldCopy parameters are both undefined.

When debugging the parameters route to get to evalList then shouldAccept runs by DragulaAndDrop.prototype._accepts in dragula-and-drop.js while shouldCopy doesn't if that give you any indication

Comment: Thanks for that - there was a bug.  The copy function was being called by the dragula engine, as opposed to the dragula-and-drop element.  So, it wasn't being called how aurelia binding expects, and therefore passing the params incorrectly.  I've released a fix in v2.0.3